# Difference between kuracisto and doktoro?

Tags: word-difference

So, why is it that Duolingo has *kuraciston* for "Doctor" when books like Teach Yourself Esperanto have *doktoro*?

Is there some sort of technical distinction between the two words? Perhaps a medical doctor vs. a PhD holder in any other field?

Comment: You perceived the distinction. That the more ambiguous _doktoro_  still is seen that often, especially in teaching material, is not surprising as "doctor" is very international. Also many languages know the same ambiguity.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The word [*kuracisto*](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/kurac.html#kurac.0isto) unambiguously means "medical doctor", while [*doktoro*](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/doktor.html#doktor.0o) mainly means "degree holder", but that word can also mean informally "medical doctor".

Answer (score 4):

I will include here the answer I posted to this very question on Duolingo three weeks ago. ([Original thread here.](https://www.duolingo.com/comment/25744605))

Original question:

> So, why is it that Duolingo has kuraciston for "Doctor" when books like Teach Yourself Esperanto have doktoro?
>
> Is there some sort of technical distinction between the two words? Perhaps a medical doctor vs. a PhD holder in any other field? Also, can kuraciston be abbreviated? As many Esperantists know — even komencanto — doktoro can be abbreviated as Dʳᵒ or D-ro.

My answer:

> This is not a case of one source using one word and another using the other. It's simply that the words mean different things. Kuracisto is a physician - someone who treats others medically. Doktoro is a title for a person who has attained a certain level of education.

Comment: Although it's implicit in you're answer, you might have added that *kuracisto* is not a title which explains the unlikeliness of an existing abbreviated form.